# А можно в Visual Studio выполнить отдельную строчку произвольного кода во время отладки?

Tags: visual-studio

Я после Райдера от Jet Brains. У всего семейства их IDE есть крутейшая фича: запускаешь отладку, нажимаешь alt + F8 и открывается окошко по типу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут можно писать любые выражения, тестить, выполнять, смотреть результат. Очень удобно. Притом, весь скоп того места, где сейчас брейкпоинт будет доступен. Можно спокойно обращаться к доступным объектам и их методам.

А вот в Visual Studio есть такое?

Comment: это не их "крутейшая фича":) это обычный отладчик. Они просто красиво визуализировали. gdb так умеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть, называется `QuickWatch` (Shift + F9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно использовать `Immediate Window`, работает так консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Воу, спасибо! Сегодня обязательно попробую!

Comment: Хоткей для вызова имедиат терминала ctrl + alt + I. A вот хоткея для очистки его - не знаю. Напишите кто нибудь, для будующих поколений ленящихся зайти в гуг пожалуйста)))